# RecursionError: The maximum recursion depth was exceeded while calling the Python object

Tags: python, kivy, init, kivymd

I have a problem with this code
The problem is as follows:
RecursionError: The maximum recursion depth was exceeded while calling the Python object
And the contractor function that produces the error in line 20
Python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.animation import Animation
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import gtts
import time
Window.clearcolor=(140/255,154/255,255/255,1)
Window.size=(400,600)
import arabic_reshaper

# install: pip install python-bidi
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape("ادخل النص هنا")    
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
class ScreenMain(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ScreenMain(),self).__init__(**kwargs)
        bidi()
    def bidi(self): 
        self.ids.input2.hint_text=bidi_text

class Chat(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title="zockchin"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Chat().run()
```

FILE .KV

```
ScreenMain
    lb:label
    BoxLayout:
        orientation : "vertical"
        padding:10
        spacing:10
        Label :
            id:label
            font_size:20
            color:1,0,0,1
            text: "Welcome to zockchin"
            background_color:0,0,.6,1
            pos_hint:{"center_x":1.5}
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:self.background_color
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size:self.size
            bold:True
            italics:True
            outline_width:3
            outline_color:.5,.9,.6,1
        TextInput:
            id: input1
            readonly: True
            font_size:20
            background_color:0,0,0
            padding:30
            foreground_color:1,1,1,5
            font_name : "Cairo-VariableFont_slnt,wght.ttf"
        TextInput:
            id: input2
            padding:30
            size_hint:1,None
            foreground_color:0,0,0,1
            font_size:20
            hint_text_color:255/255,0,0,1
            background_normal:""
            background_color:1,1,1,1
            font_name : "/home/zyad/Desktop/chat/cccc/ElMessiri-VariableFont_wght.ttf"
        Button:
            text: "Submet"
            on_release:root.click()
            background_color:(1,1,1,.02)
            background_normal:""
            size_hint:(1,.6)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:(0,0,.6,1)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size:self.size
                    radius:[70]
```

Although **kwargs has been added to bypass this error, I do not know why this urges

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [minimal, reproducible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your `super()` call.  It shouldn't be necessary to pass any parameters to super() as since [PEP-3135](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/), calling `super()` is equivalent to `super(__class__, <firstarg>)` where `<firstarg>` is `self` for an instance method or `cls` for a class method

You're getting a recursion error because you're passing `ScreenMain()` instead of just the type `ScreenMain`, which is causing it to create a new instance of ScreenMain which then calls `ScreenMain.__init__()` which then calls `ScreenMain()` again, etc.

Unless you're actually working in an old version of Python where the parameters to super() are not optional, I would just change the class declaration to :

```
class ScreenMain(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        bidi()
    def bidi(self): 
        self.ids.input2.hint_text=bidi_text
```

If you are working in the older version, then just update it to :

```
class ScreenMain(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ScreenMain,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        bidi()
    def bidi(self): 
        self.ids.input2.hint_text=bidi_text
```